# How to navigate to another Powers App, screen, and pass context when screen is passed in as a variable?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I want to have a list of items that the user can select, and based on their selection, I need to navigate to a specific screen.

To do this, I have a table, and in the table is the Human readable name of the form, and a unique value.

When the user selects the item, I have a switch statement on the unique value that navigates the user to the right screen and passes some context information, kind of like this:

```
Switch(MyPropertyValue,
   "FormA", Navigate(FormA,ScreenTransition.None, {MyVar:123}),
   "FormB", Navigate(OtherForm,ScreenTransition.None, {MyVar:123}),
)
```

This works fine,  but now there's a few places I need this navigation logic, so rather than duplicate it, I put it in an output function property of a component

[image]

So I made a function called GetScreen and all it does is return the screen based on a switch statement, so then I can just navigate to whatever GetScreen returns.  So the GetScreen function takes a text parameter, and returns a Screen object.

[image]

So now in my app I can do convert a text value from a database to a screen object and navigate to it:

```
UpdateContext(
    {
        Screen: Navigator_1.GetScreen(ThisItem.ScreenName)
        });

Navigate(Screen, ScreenTransition.None, 
    {
        RecordID: ThisItem.RecordID
    });
```

My problem now is that my target screen does not recognize any of the context properties I pass into it.  It only recognizes the context properties if I explicitly navigate to a screen, as apposed to navigating to a screen based on a variable.  No errors are reported in my screens either.

I think I can recreate this even without a function property.  If I did this for example, it would still fail.

```
UpdateContext(
    {
        Screen: Switch(MyPropertyValyue,"FormA", FormA, "FormB", MyOtherForm)
    });

Navigate(Screen, ScreenTransition.None, 
    {
        RecordID: ThisItem.RecordID
    });
```

Is there any way to pass context around, even when the target screen is passed in to the navigate functionas a variable?